# Log4j кастомный аппендер для StringProperty

Tags: java, log4j

Есть `StringProperty` "забиндиный" в `TextArea`. Необходимо выводить логи уровня "Warning" и выше в данный `StringProperty`.

Собственно, интересует сам код аппендера и в большей степени конфиг кастомного аппендера для XML.

Comment: { 
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, file

log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender

log4j.appender.file.File=log_file.log
    }

вот пример настроек.
log4j.rootLogger=INFO указывает с какого уровня и выше логировать.
ты это хотел?

Comment: @ЦовакСаакян. Прочитайте вопрос внимательнее. Меня интересует конфиг кастомного аппендера. Иначе, как прописать собственный аппендер в xml конфиг.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Итак, объявление аппендера:

```
@Plugin(name="MyCustomAppender", category="Core", elementType="appender", printObject=true)

public class Appender extends AbstractAppender {

    private final ReadWriteLock rwLock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();
    private final Lock readLock = rwLock.readLock();

    protected Appender(String name, Filter filter, Layout<? extends Serializable> layout, boolean ignoreExceptions) {
        super(name, filter, layout, ignoreExceptions);
    }

    @PluginFactory
    public static Appender createAppender(
            @PluginAttribute("name") String name,
            @PluginElement("Layout") Layout<? extends Serializable> layout,
            @PluginElement("Filter") final Filter filter,
            @PluginAttribute("otherAttribute") String otherAttribute) {
        if (name == null) {
            LOGGER.error("No name provided for MyCustomAppenderImp");
            return null;
        }
        if (layout == null) {
            layout = PatternLayout.createDefaultLayout();
        }
        return new Appender(name, filter, layout, true);
    }

    @Override
    public void append(LogEvent logEvent) {

        readLock.lock();
        try {
            final byte[] bytes = getLayout().toByteArray(logEvent);

            //Здесь меняем значение у StringProperty
            String past = MainViewController.textAreaMessages.get()==null ?"":MainViewController.textAreaMessages.get();
            StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder().append(past).append(new String(bytes, "UTF-8"));
            MainViewController.textAreaMessages.set(s.toString());

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            if (!ignoreExceptions()) {
                throw new AppenderLoggingException(ex);
            }
        } finally {
            readLock.unlock();
        }
    }
}
```

Конфигурация аппендера в `.xml` файле:

```
<Appenders>

    ...

    <MyCustomAppender name="toStringProperty" >
            <PatternLayout pattern=":%m%n" />
    </MyCustomAppender>
</Appenders>

<Loggers>

    ...

    <Logger name="com.oaks" level="info">
        <AppenderRef ref="toStringProperty"/>
    </Logger>


</Loggers>
```